# Batch file to rename jpg

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with all jpg and this is format 1UYK08HJ_20140403165858071_SYPTE1-PC but i want it rename like this 
1UYK08HJ_SYPTE1-PC_20140403165858071.jpg. but when i run this script it always ends up with

```
 .%~nA_1UYK08HJ.jpg.jpg.jpg
```

this is my batch script..

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\export" || exit /b
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *_*.jpg') do (
  for /f "tokens=1* eol=_ delims=_" %%A in ("%%F") do ren "%%F" "%%~nA_%%B%%~xF"
)
popd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\export" || exit /b
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_." %%A in ('dir /b /a-d *_*.jpg') do (
  Echo ren %%A_%%B_%%C.%%D %%A_%%C_%%B.%%D
)
popd
```

Remove the echo when you see correct output.

Answer (score -1):

In the (Window's) folder's `command line(cmd)` run

```
ren *.* *.jpg
```

Comment: How should that rename something like `1UYK08HJ_20140403165858071_SYPTE1-PC.jpg` to `1UYK08HJ_SYPTE1-PC_20140403165858071.jpg`?